# Interrupt for a systemcall?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu, system-calls, hardware

Hey guys just wanted to confirm that I correctly understand how a systemcall is invoked.

So if a programm needs access to a kernel functionality it loads the system call number into a register and calls a software interrupt(in linux 0x80).

Then the NVIC(or AVIC) makes the processor jump to the beginning of the interrupt handler and makes the cpu go into supervisor mode.

Then the interrupt handler gets the system call number and jumps to the kernel code that handles the system call.

In the end the programm goes back to its original state and continuous running.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work that way because interrupt vectors also have permission bits. If the user mode processes could just trigger an interrupt vector to jump into  kernel mode, it would be able to break the system by triggering whatever fault it pleases.

Instead, on 32 bits x86, the `int 0x80` interrupt is given a user mode permission so, when processes use it, they are still in user mode once the interrupt is started. The interrupt handler will then use the `sysenter` assembly instruction to jump into kernel mode. The `sysenter` instruction jumps to the address specified in a register set at boot from kernel mode.

The equivalent for 64 bits x86 is `syscall`. Actually, on x64 platforms, the `syscall` instruction is used directly by glibc and libstdc++.